# Can't acess kubenetes pod on Azure linux vm

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am running the Kubernetes cluster on Azure Linux VM. I have installed kubectl and using minikube to run my flask application.
When run
`minikube service flask-service --url`
the URL I get can't be used to access the pod
So my question is how do I map my vm's IP to pods IP. Such that when I hit `vmIP:port` I should get the response from my Kubernetes pod

Comment: not so relevant but why not using azure kubernetes service: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/ ?

Comment: for some certain reason, I can't use AKS. So if you can help me with this scenerio

Comment: You can try to create a service with type `NodePort` and then you can access the VM IP address with the port as you wish.

Comment: Can you put more details regarding your service? 
Have you tried creating a service with type `NodePort`?

While `ClusterIP` is the default service-type which allows the service to be only accessible from inside the cluster, to access the service from outside the cluster you should specify the type of service is `NodePort`. A NodePort allows you to configure the port on which you intend to access the service from outside the cluster.